# How to create a dataframe from specific values of another dataframe but including duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I am pulling only specific names from an original csv of over 1000 names. But I only want specific names, mission accomplished. However the problem is that I have multiple people with the same name, there are two Jack's, two John's, etc. There is not last name column. The problem is when I run my isin code, it only picks up the first instance of Jack, it doesn't pick up duplicate values. Is there a way to pick up duplicate values? Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd

#Import your dataframe 
d1 = pd.read_csv("D1Reset_2020-01-09.CSV")

from datetime import date

#Change Notional Column type from Object to String then Int
d1['Bank_Account'] = pd.to_numeric(d1['Bank_Account'],errors='coerce')

#Create a new dataframe with only the respective names we want to analyze
array = [‘Jack, ‘John’, ’Patrick’, ’Kelly’]

d1 = d1.loc[d1['Name'].isin(array)].copy()
```

Comment: Can you share a minimal part of the data you have to help us reproduce the problem?

Comment: With a minimal dataframe, I didn't get the issue you had with using the same `.loc` and `isin` mechanism. Confirm that everyhting is okay while reading the data etc.